# mpi main process not killed when shell is closed

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am running [LAMMPS](http://lammps.sandia.gov/) in parallel mode using mpi, and I've noticed something strange happening.

If I close the shell from which the process was launched, the slaves processes are killed, but the master is not:

(With open shell)

```
valesori@eris:~$ ps aux | grep lammps
valesori  3985  0.2  0.0 208124  7508 pts/26   Sl+  13:59   0:00 mpirun -np 4 lammps -in in.create_bonds
valesori  3987 96.9  0.2 406148 21956 pts/26   Rl   13:59   0:09 lammps -in in.create_bonds
valesori  3988 94.2  0.2 406060 22192 pts/26   Rl   13:59   0:09 lammps -in in.create_bonds
valesori  3989 98.5  0.2 406040 21888 pts/26   Rl   13:59   0:09 lammps -in in.create_bonds
valesori  3991 94.2  0.2 406044 21944 pts/26   Rl   13:59   0:09 lammps -in in.create_bonds
valesori  4102  0.0  0.0  14228   936 pts/27   S+   13:59   0:00 grep lammps
```

(With closed shell)

```
valesori@eris:~$ ps aux | grep lammps
valesori  3985 15.1  0.1 208124  8244 ?        Rl   13:59   0:04 mpirun -np 4 lammps -in in.create_bonds
valesori  4285  0.0  0.0  14228   924 pts/27   S+   13:59   0:00 grep lammps
```

The only thing I've noticed is that the state of the master process changes from Sl+ to Rl. R should stand for "running/runnable" while S should stand for "interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)"; l means that the process is multi-threaded and + that it is in the foreground process group (see for example [this network post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360252/what-do-the-stat-column-values-in-ps-mean)).

If I launch the same script in serial mode, the process is killed normally when the shell is closed.

Is this a known bug of mpi? If not, what could be the reason?

(I am using Open MPI version 1.10.2)

**UPDATE**

I've actually realized that the outcome is in some way not reproducible. I've had 3 different outcomes up until now:

1. Master and slaves are killed when the shell is closed.
2. Only the slaves are killed when the shell is closed.
3. No process is killed when the shell is closed.

Comment: What is your MPI implementation? Best to add the respective tag.

Comment: @Zulan added. It's Open MPI 1.10.2

Comment: This seems like an implementation problem and the version is a bit dated. Try updating to the latest one.